# display visual force page without modification button

Tags: apex, visualforce, button, detail-page

I have a `visualforce page` called `/apex/fileDetails` and i include it in my object as button but when i click on it, the page is opened but with the button modification at the bottom of page (it's the red area i marked at the bottom which allow me to modify the page) :
[image: my visual force page]

how can i hide automatically this area when i click the button who display this page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the [developer mode](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=pages_dev_mode.htm&language=en_US) footer you are seeing at the bottom of the screen. It is used for debugging and developing apex pages. It needs to be enabled on a per user basis and it is only displayed to users that have "**Development Mode**" checked on their user record.

From [Using the Development Mode Footer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_tools_edit_toolbar.htm):

> Click the Disable Development Mode button ( [image: Disable development mode icon]) to turn off development mode entirely. Development mode
>   remains off until you enable it again from your personal information
>   page in your personal settings.

Comment: so there's no way to hide it without clicking the `Disable Development Mode button ` ?

Comment: Correct but it is only displayed to users that have "Development Mode" checked on their user record.